# SQL SELECT DISTINCT and GROUP BY query not working

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, distinct

I have a tabel with e-mail adresses and additional data. Now i want to get all e-mailadresses that exsist multiple times in the table with different genders. I tried the folowing query:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(DISTINCT(gender)) FROM `email_data` WHERE COUNT(DISTINCT(gender)) > 1 GROUP BY email
```

I get the folowing result: #1111 - Invalid use of group function

I tried different variations including GROUP BY email, gender. but nothing seems to work. If i remove the WHERE part of the query it works. Can someone help me out?

Comment: put COUNT(DISTINCT(gender)) > 1 condition in having clause. so it look like, 

SELECT email, COUNT(DISTINCT(gender)) 
FROM `email_data` 
having COUNT(DISTINCT(gender)) > 1 
GROUP BY email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put aggregation functions in the `WHERE` clause.  They go in the `HAVING` clause.  However, it is usually more efficient to just compare the max and min values for this purpose:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(DISTINCT gender)
FROM `email_data`
GROUP BY email
HAVING MIN(gender) <> MAX(gender)
```

Comment: Works! Thx for the help.